# Polymer not unlistening properly

Tags: templates, polymer, polymer-1.0

[image: listeners grow]

I use Polymer.Templatizer to stamp templates of `paper-input` collections into a `custom-element` which has a listener `'change':'_doStuff'`.
Basically when I stamp 20 `paper-input`s via `Polymer.dom(this).appendChild(template.root)` a bunch of listeners are added , as you can see in the graph. 
Then I call another function that goes through all of those elements and does `Polymer.dom(paperInput.parentNode).removeChild(paperInput)` and adds another set of inputs. But it just doesn't detach listeners on those for some reason and the heap is growing with every iteration... 
The listener `change` on the host element, I believe, is neither detached.

What am I doing wrongly?

EDIT: I know what it is, it's not garbage collection problem, but Polymer creates anonymous Polymer.Base instances when templatizing and actually puts all template's children into those. of course the instances are not removed in any way. I wish I knew how to kill those not to reduce performance of the app. By defining custom elements instead? Looks like an overhead to me...

Comment: Chrome doesn't release the memory immediately when a component is removed from the DOM. AFAIK only when Chrome experiences some memory pressure, probably also some other things too, but usually not immediately anyway, it runs garbage collection. When garbage collection disposes removed elements and JS objects, the components and event handlers should be disposed together. It shouldn't matter if the listeners weren't removed in advance. If your code keeps a reference to the element or JS objects, then GC can't dispose them. That's the responsibility of your code to not keep references.

Comment: You could create a bug report or feature request in https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/

Comment: Have already done so

Answer (score 0):

A way to free your memory could be to unlisten all of your listeners before you detach your elements, in order them to be unreferenced first. For example :

```
for (var i = 0; i < inputList.length; i++) {
  this.unlisten(inputList[i], 'change', 'doStuff');
  Polymer.dom(inputList[i].parentNode).removeChild(inputList[i]);
}
```